# how to compile html, css and js code inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to create a simple jsfiddle app

On the final result - click on the button inside the iframe should makes the title background `silver`

How to do this?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
var ht = $('#ht').val();
var cs = $('#cs').val();
var js = $('#js').val();
var str = $('#frame')[0].innerHTML;
str = str.replace('~ht', ht);
str = str.replace('~cs', cs);
str = str.replace('~js', js);
 $('#frame').attr('src', str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>RUN</button>
<br><br>
 <textarea id="ht">
 <button>CLICK</button>
 <div class='title'>lorem</div>
 </textarea>
 
 <textarea id="cs">
 .title{
 background:gold;
 }
 </textarea>
 
 <textarea id="js">
 $('button').on('click', function(){
 $('.title').css('background', 'silver');
 });
 </textarea>
 
 <iframe id="frame">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <style>~st</style>
 </head>
 <body>
 ~ht
 </body>
 </html>
 </iframe>
```

Comment: Viewing Karans answere shows, you have been 3 letters from your goal away. `.attr('src', str)` adding `doc` like `.attr('srcdoc', str)` would do the trick :D

Comment: you actually using jquery, but you dont have jquery in your iframe... so you may have to pass this too or use plain javascript

Comment: @Dwza, tried to place jquery inside `ht` textarea - but finall click on resulting button doesn't work - title is not silver

Comment: Reverted the question to its `original state`. Op added the answer received from **Karan** and edited his question with the answer.

Comment: @qadenza Just explaining what you have done. Thats all.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, no that's much more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`srcdoc`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp) to specifies the HTML content of the page to show in the inline frame.

**Edit**

Added `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` inside `<textarea id="ht">` so iframe could load `jquery` and bind `$('button').click`.

Corrected `$('.title').css('background', 'silver');`.

There is something wrong with `stackoverflow` `fiddle` I guess. It doesn't allow me to use `</script>`. So I need to write some work around and used `</ script></html>'.replace('/ scrip', '/scrip');`.

Now it is working as expected in question and on button click it will change color.

Try it below.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var str = '<html><body>~ht</body><style>~cs</style><script>~js</ script></html>'.replace('/ scrip', '/scrip');
 
  str = str.replace('~ht', $('#ht').val());
  str = str.replace('~cs', $('#cs').val());
  str = str.replace('~js', $('#js').val());

  $('#frame').attr('srcdoc', str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>RUN</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id="ht">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button>CLICK</button>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
</textarea>

<textarea id="cs">
  .title {
    background:gold;
  }
</textarea>

<textarea id="js">
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.title').css('background', 'silver');
  });
</textarea>

<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

Comment: btw. he could use `$('#frame')[0].innerHTML;` as he did in his sample to receive possible existing content

Comment: *click on the button inside the iframe should makes the title background* `silver`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping then he should add a button, doing this ^^ see https://jsfiddle.net/7rw1Ld9p/1/

Comment: Not exactly what the OP wanted to do - But yes it an inline trick.

Comment: its just a sample... OP allready has a button build an inserted. :) even if there is a mistake in his source.. `$('.title').css{'background', 'silver');` there is a wrong curly bracket

Comment: could someone follow the jsfiddle logic - click on RUN button creates the button inside the iframe and click on that button makes the title silver

Comment: @qadenza Can you follow that logic ?

Comment: @qadenza I said this because that how you can learn. Its a not free coding service where you get what you want. try for yourself for the sake of your own learning. You down-voted  **Karan** answer and edited your question to add the information (srcdoc) you received from this answer. this is not good at all.

Comment: I have up-voted your answer Karan. its a very good answer according to me.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, because you or someone upvoted that answer which is not a solution. The goal is not to fill the iframe with content but make some changes by clicking on a resulting button

Comment: @qadenza edit your question to add the specific you want. Your question does NOT says that. fix your question atleast.

Comment: @Dwza, btw. he could use `$('#frame')[0].innerHTML;`. This will only work for `first` time. If `user` click second time it will not work.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, thanks, And I've changed few mistakes like `.css` one. Also `OP` was using `$('button')` which need `jquery` so added `script` into `textarea`. Now it will make `.title` `background` to `silver`.

Comment: @Karan thats true, but since he want to pass the content when pressing run button (at least he sayed that in the comments) my comment is actually useless :) and I did not changed the OP's code mistakes to mention that he has some problems there.. changing the code will may lead to keep the wrong code in his work because he thinks the posted code is exactly the code in his work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<button>RUN</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id="ht">
    <button onclick="changeBg();">CLICK</button><div class='title'>lorem</div>
</textarea>
<textarea id="cs">.title{background:gold;}</textarea>
<textarea id="js">
    function changeBg(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='silver';
    }
</textarea>

<iframe id="frame">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    ~js
    <style>~st</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  ~ht
  </body>
 </iframe>
```

Here is a fiddle you can use

https://jsfiddle.net/7rw1Ld9p/2/

This answere is according to @Karan's answere.

Comment: of course not. the iframe should get its content after a click on RUN button. and only title should be silver, not entire iframe

Comment: @qadenza first of all, guess nobody is writing your code. SOF is here to help people. second you never sayed the content should appear after hitting run. So I'm sure karans and my ansere should simpley help you to achive your goal. You can't expact to get your total code here. And by the way... there is no title at all!

Comment: @Dwza, I agree with you. Also this is helpful answer and no need to delete. +1. @ qadenza  This platform is not coding service that will give you what you want for free. People help other and got help from other community members. But to get some help you need to do some research and show what you have tried. In answer they can show you the direction following which you can reach to your desired result on your own.

Comment: Hey @Karan I did not deleted the vote. I was even wondering why someone obviously downvoted your answer because its actually exact this what OP is searching for. He only needs to fit this to his use case. Actually I was the first one who voted your question, and you still have it :)